# Do probabilities exist in reality?

Tags: probability, philosophical

I came across the seemingly interesting work of [William Briggs](https://wmbriggs.com/) in relation to probability and statistics. He make some bold claims, like the following:

> Probability does not exist as a thing, as a Platonist would hold, but as an idea in the mind. Probability is thus purely epistemological. This is not proved here, but [11] is an essential reference.

(from [here](https://wmbriggs.com/public/Briggs.Reality.Based.Prob.Stats.pdf))

The book referred to makes similar claims. Perhaps a key quote:

> Probability is widely misunderstood for two main reasons: the confusion between
>   ontological and epistemological truth, and the conflation of acts or decisions with
>   probability; [188] also insists on this distinction. These errors are discussed in the
>   next chapter, but it’s helpful here to have a précis. A thing is ontologically true if it exists, and it is ontologically false if it does not. An epistemological truth is when we know, given certain unambiguously specified evidence, that a proposition is so. Epistemologically true propositions do not have to be ontologically true. We know the proposition “Mike is green” is true given “All dragons are green and Mike is a dragon”. This is an epistemological conditional, or local, truth. But we also know the major part of the premise is ontologically false because there are no dragons, green or otherwise. That we know it is ontologically false—that we know there are no dragons—is itself both an ontological and an epistemological truth, conditional on observation. The lack of dragons is ontologically contingent. The subjects of contingent propositions can only be or not be, exist or not, they cannot have ontological probabilities: they can only be ontologically true or false. Yet since we might not know whether a thing be or not, propositions can and do have epistemological probabilities. Probability is the simple extension of logic to situations where the evidence does not guarantee epistemological certainty.

For instance, what is the probability that an asteroid annihilate life on Earth in 2020? Surely the answer depends on our knowledge of astronomy, particularly in our capacity to track and model bodies in space. As this knowledge has evolved over time, the answer would also vary over time. And yet, if we were to "know everything about the universe", perhaps our answer would have no uncertainty anymore, and thus we would know for sure if an asteroid would or not annihilate life on Earth.

But is everything like the example above? More generally, **is probability found in nature?** (independent of our epistemological states) Or is is necessarily a human concept, always reflecting (and thus conditional on) our state of knowledge?

Comment: Have you considered posting this on the [philosophy site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), where it is likely on topic?

Comment: @whuber I debated about it, but since I found the [philosophical] tag, I thought I would give it a try here first.

Comment: It certainly is of interest to many in this community, but a review of [the list of our on-topic questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) suggests it doesn't belong here.

Comment: There certainly are non-epistemic theories of probability: see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/ for an overview & references. Hacking's *The Emergence of Probability* gives a genealogical account of the concept(s).